# How to fix the windows batch file to correctly push changes to git?

Tags: c#, git

Batch File:

```
echo @off
pushd %1
git add .
git commit -m %2
git push origin %3
```

Here is the method through which I am executing this script:

```
private static void RunPushGitScript(string scriptPath, string repositoryPath, string headBranch, string commitMessage)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(scriptPath);
            info.CreateNoWindow = false;
            info.Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", repositoryPath, "Updated Packages", headBranch);
            var process = Process.Start(info);
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
```

I am only getting "Updated" keyword as the commit message and not the complete message.
So how can I fix that in this code?

Comment: Does it work outside of your parent process? What happens when you run the script by itself

Comment: probably need quotes around your message because of the space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote your message in the string.format

```
    private static void RunPushGitScript(string scriptPath, string repositoryPath, string headBranch, string commitMessage)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(scriptPath);
        info.CreateNoWindow = false;
        info.Arguments = String.Format("{0} '{1}' {2}", repositoryPath, "Updated Packages", headBranch);
        var process = Process.Start(info);
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```